# Which shard iterator type should I use, if I have to read messages from stream before application started running

Tags: java, amazon-kinesis

Which shard iterator type should I use if I have to read messages from the stream before the application started running

Our code looks like this right now, but shard iterator type LATEST doesn't read messages which were posted into the stream before the application started. How should I set this?

```
private String getShardIterator() {

       GetShardIteratorRequest itReq = GetShardIteratorRequest.builder()

               .streamName(streamName)

               .shardIteratorType("LATEST")

               .shardId("shardId-000000000000")

               .build();
```

Refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/kinesis/model/GetShardIteratorRequest.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the most old messages available, you need to set the shard iterator type to `TRIM_HORIZON`, which will start from the oldest record available in the shard.

If you additionally know the seq num to start with, you can set it to `AT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER` or `AFTER_SEQUENCE_NUMBER` and additionally provide starting sequence number parameter.

The `LATEST` starts with the most recent record published after you subscribed.